# Are eigenvalues of a matrix always bounded?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For a given matrix $A$, under which assumptions are the corresponding eigenvalues bounded? Or is this always the case?

Comment: When a matrix has finitely many entries, there are only finitely many eigenvalues and hence they are bounded.

Comment: How do you define "bounded"? Do you want their absolute value to be bounded by some function of the entries of the matrix? Of the determinant?... As long as you don't give the exact definition here, the answer by @edm is the best there is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a non-singular square matrix, there are situations where the entry of your matrix are very small numbers. That can lead to eigen-values very close zero. if you write a condition number of those matrices, you would see that the number may grow unbounded.

Comment: But still the value of the eigenvalues itself is bounded below by 0 right? Meaning that they are all greater or equal 0

Comment: The question is quite vague. For a *given* matrix the eigenvalues are non-existent, or just numbers in some field. In the latter case, if there is just finitely many of them, then yes, they are bounded, and if there are infinitely many of them (say, $A$ is infinite dimensional), then they may not be bounded.

Comment: Ok sorry my question was not very concise, but of course if there are finitely many then they are bounded. Thank you